# How can I accomodate hotfixes in the KanBan board in JIRA

Tags: kanban, jira

Say I have 4 tickets in Done state in the Kanban board. I plan to release them together after a detailed QA which would take me about 2 days.

However I have this one ticket which is a hotfix and it needs to be released right away. If I hit the release button, I can not choose which tickets go into that release since all 5 tickets will get selected. How do I make sure that single ticket goes out of the Done column in the board.

Comment: Can't it just idle on the board in the done columns until you release the next version? Does it really need its own version?

Comment: I did not think about it in that way. Makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JIRA Kanban board has a default filter:

> fixVersion in unreleasedVersions() OR fixVersion is EMPTY

You can find your filter under Board(Top right)->Configure->General->Kanban board sub-filter

Just set the fixVersion of that task to a released version number and it will be removed from the board.

That is actually the same the release button does, it just sets the fixVersion for all tasks in done as a batch and then marks the version released.